# AngularJS 1.4.8 creates an empty option in select when my model is updated

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs

I have a service where you can select different types of agreement documents. When I load the page for the first time, the agreement drop down is always populated correctly and the correct value is displayed in the browser. The agreement is fetched from the `vm.getAgreement()` function. Like this:

[image]

However it is also possible to update the AgreementDocumentType. This is done by calling the `vm.save()` function which in turn calls `vm.getAgreement()` again. I debugged the code to see when the error happens and it is when `vm.agreement = data;` is set for the second time. The object `data` is however exactly the same as the first time, `vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType` is `3`. Every other field is updated correctly but the select list looks like this after save:

[image]

Looking at the generated HTML the weird thing is that the option with value 3 is marked as selected, as it should be, but still no value is displayed in the drop down list: `value="3" selected="selected">`. If I then select `Agreement3` or any other value the empty value (`<option value="? number:3 ?"></option>`) directly disappears from the list. I'm using AngularJS version 1.4.8 if it can be of any help. My best guess is that when `vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType` is re-populated the binding is lost for a split second and therefore an empty value is created and for some reason not removed until the drop down is interacted with. Has anyone experienced this and solved it?

Generated HTML:

```
<select name="Agreement" class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-touched" ng-model="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType" required="">
    <option value="? number:3 ?"></option>
     <!-- ngRepeat: option in vm.agreementTypes -->
     <option ng-selected="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType == option.id" ng-repeat="option in vm.agreementTypes" ng-value="option.id" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="1">
         Agreement1
     </option>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: option in vm.agreementTypes -->
     <option ng-selected="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType == option.id" ng-repeat="option in vm.agreementTypes" ng-value="option.id" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="2">
         Agreement2
     </option>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: option in vm.agreementTypes -->
     <option ng-selected="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType == option.id" ng-repeat="option in vm.agreementTypes" ng-value="option.id" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="3" selected="selected">
         Agreement3
     </option>
     <!-- end ngRepeat: option in vm.agreementTypes -->
</select>
```

Html:

```
<select name="Agreement" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType" required>
    <option ng-selected="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType == option.id"
            ng-repeat="option in vm.agreementTypes"
            ng-value="option.id">
        {{option.label}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
vm.agreementTypes = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Agreement1' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Agreement2' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Agreement3' }
];

vm.save = function () {
    agreementResource.update({ agreementId: vm.agreementId }, vm.agreement).$promise.then(function () {
        toastr.success('Agreement saved');
        vm.getAgreement();
    });
};

vm.getAgreement = function () {
    agreementResource.get({ agreementId: vm.agreementId }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        vm.agreement = data;
    });
}

vm.getAgreement();
```

Comment: What is in `data`?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Correct values for `vm.agreement`. `vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType` is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because you are building the options manually, angularjs internals are not binding your model properly when it gets changed from scope side, there is more than `selected="selected"` to do, this internal are made by the `ngOptions` directive, consider using it instead of building your options list manually.

```
<select
    name="Agreement"
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="vm.agreement.AgreementDocumentType"
    ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in vm.agreementTypes"
    required>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code worked! I had tried exactly your code but with the extension `track by option.id` in ng-options. Removing this got it working.

Comment: There is a note about using `track by` and `select as` together on the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions. It can cause some issues.